# How to use Apex application on iFrame?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an Apex 19.2 Application.

The application is inserted in another website (with a different domain) as an iFrame :

```
<iframe src= "URL of my apex App" style= "width:1200px; height:750px; max-width:100%; margin:auto; display:block;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I have a custom authentication scheme with the cookie configured as **SameSite none** and **Secure**

In the Security Attributes, of the app, **Embed in Frames** is set to **Allow**

The integration of my app in the external website works but the cookies are not created and all the session features are not working. The same app works just fine with the cookies when opened directly not from an iframe.

Does anyone know how to solve that please ?

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to Set `Cookie Path to ‘/apex; SameSite=none’` Please go through this URL https://www.jmjcloud.com/blog/upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-and-the-impact-for-apex-apps-running-in-an-iframe

Comment: @amitbhosale Thanks for you answer but the problem was much more complex than that. Actually my app was working fine and the path of the cookie is not important it can be "/", "/apex" or whatever. The problem was that since my app is opening in an iframe its cookies are considered third party cookies and Safari just blocks them. And it has nothing to do with my app configuration. It may be useful for someone having the same problem.

Comment: Can you please disable Safari's Prevent cross-site tracking preference and verify

Comment: Of course if I disable cross-site tracking preference, it's going to work. But my app is integrated in other people websites and browsed from their computers whom I have no control on